# How can I get outlines to just go around the edge of object?

Tags: compositing-nodes, freestyle, toon-shading, lineart

I've tried a few methods of rendering outlines but I just want it to go around the silhouette. Freestyle and the solidify method both give me too many outlines or dont show up at certain angles like the ones I have circled in red.

Solidify method outlining too many edges.

[image]

Freestyle lines clipping or not showing up on rounded edges

[image]

Id like the outlines to be more like how they show up in the viewport, when I simply select the object. Example below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using Freesyle with only the Edge Type "External Contour" checked and "Same Object" under "Freestyle Strokes > Chaining" unchecked.

[image]